# PHP create and write form

Tags: php

I have a form with two fields. The first textbox the users enter information into is what I would like to name the file that is being saved, and the second textarea is for what I would like written into the file. I am able to write to a file I have already created using php coding below which I did simply to test the function:

```
<?php

//  If a session already exists, this doesn't have any effect.
session_start();

//  Sets the current directory to the directory this script is running in
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

//  Breakpoint
if( empty($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['username'] == '' ) echo 'There is no session username';
if( empty($_POST['CodeDescription']) || $_POST['CodeDescription'] == '' ) echo 'There is no POST CodeDescription';

//  Get current working directory
echo getcwd();
//  This should output   /home/revo/public_html/evo/users

//  This is assuming we are working from the current directory that is running this PHP file.
$USER_DIRECTORY = 'users/'.$_SESSION['username'];

//  Makes the directory if it doesn't exist
if(!is_dir($USER_DIRECTORY)):
mkdir($USER_DIRECTORY);
endif;

//  Put together the full path of the file we want to create
$FILENAME = $USER_DIRECTORY.'/'.$_POST['CodeDescription'].'.txt';

if( is_file( $FILENAME ) ):

// Open the text file
  $f = fopen($FILENAME, "w");

// Write text
  file_put_contents($FILENAME, $_POST['Code']); 

// Close the text file
  fclose($f);

// Open file for reading, and read the line
  $f = fopen($FILENAME, "r");

else:

echo 'Filename already exists';

endif;

?>
```

However I am unsure how to check to see if a file with the name they enter into the first box exists, and then if not create it, then write the information from the second box into the file.

Comment: For debugging, try putting a `var_dump($_POST['desired_name']);` at the top of your file to make sure the POST variables are being received properly from your html `<form>`. You should then see the value of your POST variable echoed at the top of your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

//  If a session already exists, this doesn't have any effect.
session_start();

//  Sets the current directory to the directory this script is running in
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

//  Breakpoint
if( empty($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['username'] == '' ) echo 'There is no session username';
if( empty($_POST['CodeDescription']) || $_POST['CodeDescription'] == '' ) echo 'There is no POST desired filename';

//  Get current working directoty
//echo getcwd();    //  Debugging output

//  This is assuming we are working from the current directory that is running this PHP file.
$USER_DIRECTORY = 'users/'.$_SESSION['username'];

//  Makes the directory if it doesn't exist
if(!is_dir($USER_DIRECTORY)) mkdir($USER_DIRECTORY);

//  Put together the full path of the file we want to create
$FILENAME = $USER_DIRECTORY.'/'.$_POST['CodeDescription'].'.txt';
//echo $FILENAME;   //  Debugging output

if( !is_file( $FILENAME ) ):

    // Open the text file, write the contents, and close it.
    file_put_contents($FILENAME, $_POST['Code']);

    //  Use file_get_contents() to read the file.
    //  $read_contents = file_get_contents($FILENAME);

else:

    echo 'Filename already exists';

endif;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you Aidan. I tried using that code, changing 'desired_name' to the first textarea name obviously that I want to make into the file name, however it jumped straight to returning "filename already exists" which it definitely doesn't and did not create anything.

Comment: @RobertEttinger because the file doesn't exists, aidan is using `is_file` which checks if the specified path is a file instead of `file_exists` which checks if file exists.

Comment: @Phuti `is_file()` checks both. See here http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php

Comment: @FactoryAidan my bad i forgot, the function returns TRUE if it is a file.

Comment: @RobertEttinger This code works. The only thing that would prevent the file from being written is the path being invalid or the folder permissions not allowing php to write to the folder.

Comment: @FactoryAidan your code will not work because `is_file` checks whether the specified file is a regular file and the file is not yet created.

Comment: It does, I had typos in there and I have it saved, thank you. as I posted to phuti I now need to see how to check to see if a directory exists based on a user currently logged in then I can add that to your guys' coding to make this work. thank you for your help.

Comment: That's exactly what he wants. My `if` statement will execute if the file either doesn't exist or is not a regular file.

Comment: @Phuti, you obviously did not read the 'Return Values' section of the php reference I shared earlier http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php  It VERY clearly states `Returns TRUE if the filename exists and is a regular file, FALSE otherwise.`.  I am not discussing this with you any further.

Comment: Is there a specific way to check to see if a directory exists (basing this off session id which is ['username'] and if not to create the directory? is it done the same way as searching for the file?

Comment: `if(!is_dir($_SESSION['username'])): mkdir($_SESSION['username']); endif;` Depending what other PHP script(s) you have in front of this script, you may need to use `session_start();` before you can access the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: I will try that Aidan and work on inputting that now, my coding in the main page calling this particular php script already has session_start() coding in there. Do I need to change anything in the create file coding you posted so it posts it in that created directory?

Comment: See updated Answer.  As it is written now.  The php script is in the `current` directory. You should manually make a directory with full permissions inside of that same directory called `users`. Then, any username sub-folders will be automatically created inside of `users`.  So `frank`'s `my_file`, would be `users/frank/my_file.txt`.  Tell me if you get any errors when you run it.

Comment: Thank you Aidan, I used your updated coding but it gives me this error: Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in /home/revo/public_html/evo/avsave/avsaveprocess.php on line 11
Filename already exists        ,   however the file most definitely doesn't exist (the directory I'm trying to create with it)  , thank you for the comment, I'm changing the directory name to users and creating it just as you stated and will run it again

Comment: Still getting the same error. Ok I changed the chmod to 777 to ensure it could write, and when finished it appeared that it went through, but came back with an internal server error 404 page (not sure if that was because it completed, but had no page to redirect to once finished), but nothing was created.

Comment: Have a look. I added `chdir(dirname(__FILE__));` to ensure the current directory is the directory the php file is running in.  See if it works. Let me know.

Comment: it came back with that server error and when I look at the error log created in that folder it gives: PHP Warning:  mkdir() [<a href='function.mkdir'>function.mkdir</a>]: No such file or directory in /home/revo/public_html/evo/avsave/users/avsaveprocess.php on line 11

Comment: I'm wondering if the $_SESSION['username'] variable is blank.  That would cause the issue.  I added this to check if it is:  `if( empty($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['username'] == '' ) echo 'There is no session username';`

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, just ran it, and for some reason now I'm getting that 500 internal server error again and nothing showing in my server log.

Comment: Do you have any way to chat? This comment section is quite full.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to chat, can chat over skype if you have it or can start a fiddle and possibly use that. I fixed where my files were and ran it again, and returned Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in /home/revo/public_html/evo/users/avsaveprocess.php on line 17
Filename already exists

Comment: Whoa.. wait here.  Your error says the php file is here `/home/revo/public_html/evo/users/avsaveprocess.php`  but you need it to be here for things to work. `/home/revo/public_html/evo/avsaveprocess.php`.  Your php file should be on the same level as the  `users` directory. Not inside it.  Move the php file up one directory and re-run.  Let me know.

Comment: oh wow. I can't believe I missed that. I'm so sorry. Hah. Ran it, and it came back file name exists. It created the folder, but no file inside of it.

Comment: Ok. We're getting somewhere.  Now we need to see why it thinks the filename exists. See updated Answer. Put this near the top.  `if( empty($_POST['desired_name']) || $_POST['desired_name'] == '' ) echo 'There is no POST desired filename';`  But remember to change `desired_name` to your actual variable.

Comment: I input that, changed ['desired_name'] to ['CodeDescription'] (what the textarea name is) and it came back with /home/revo/public_html/evoFilename already exists

Comment: Just double checking.  But are you using your original `fopen()` command or are you using `file_put_contents()`?  And if you are using `file_put_contents()`  are you using the same variable name for the filename... such as `$file` or `$FILE` or `$FILENAME`.  It seems like you're using `file_put_contents($file,$contents)` where my code would have it like `file_put_contents($FILENAME,$contents)`  or better yet  `file_put_contents($FILENAME, $_POST['Code']);`

Comment: I'm using your code above just as you have it, so I'm not using file_put_contents but if need be I'll change that line and test.

Comment: I just changed the Answer to match your variable names and everything. Run it. Let me know the error message.  And are you sure it didn't make the text file and telling us so.. But we just think it's not telling the truth?  I'd check to be sure.  This code is squeaky clean.

Comment: That resolved it. The changes at the end. Wow. Thank you Aidan for your help. I can't say that enough, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm stoked to have helped worked through it with you and get to a functioning solution.

Comment: You and me both, I know the basics and have worked through alot of other things to get stuff running but this I was having a time with. Marked for right answer and I'll up this soon as I have the rep. Again, thank you. I'm super excited, and I learned so much.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$_POST` to get the contents of the `textarea` and `input` field.

```
 $file_name =  $_POST['filename'];
 $contents = $_POST['code'];
 $file = '../evo/avsave/'.$file_name . '.txt';
 //writing the file
 if(!file_exists($file)){
   file_put_contents($file,$contents);
  }else{
    echo 'File exists';
  }
```

Comment: thank you for the assistance Phuti however I am not sure where in the code to ensure its putting the newly created file into the proper folder

Comment: @RobertEttinger the code above with put the file in the current directory.

Comment: Excellent, thank you both. Though now that I'm looking at it, putting it in the current directory may be a little tough though I might be able to go that way. I need these files based on the user that is currently logged into a session. Now I need to find out how to search to see if a directory exists based on a current user logged in so I can save these files there.